# Identifying Danfoss compressor controller connector

Tags: connector, identification

I have a Danfoss refrigeration compressor that is connected to its electronic controller via a three-pin connector. (I.e. the connections for the three motor windings.) I am looking for the name of this plug and corresponding receptacle.

The dimensions of the plug are approximately 20x30mm. The pin holes are separated by 11 or 12mm (center to center).

The pins of the opposite look like solid, round metal pins with a diameter of approximately 1.5mm and a length of approximately 5mm (maybe more).

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's look like a terminal plug 8615-4 it is specific to danfoss 101N0210 serie  (see the [Danfoss catalog](http://kontes.gr/pdf/compressors_BD.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much! It never occurred to me that Danfoss would have the plugs for sale. Duh... (For others with the same question, the key word is: "remote kit" in the Danfoss catalog.)